# 2002 Mercedes E320 - Exhaust getting into the cabin of the vehicle and causing headaches

Tags: exhaust, mercedes-benz, leak, smell, e320

Experiencing exhaust fumes in the car.  It's causing eyes burning and headaches after driving the car for 30 minutes. The Dealer checked and found nothing wrong but every time after driving the car for about 30 minutes, I have head ache and my eyes burn from the air coming through the vents.

***How can I troubleshoot where the exhaust leak is?***

***What could be the source if the exhaust gasses are getting into the cars cabin?***

Comment: What exactly is your question? As it stands, there'd be just about no way someone on SE could answer this (sort-of) question. A person would have to be present and inspecting the vehicle to figure out if there is an exhaust leak, and secondly where it would be coming from.

Answer (score 1):

Years ago when I used to inspect vehicles for a living. There was one thing that would cause such nasty fumes after 30 minutes or so. It was over spray from the anti-rust coating that sometimes would end up on exhaust parts and cause pungent sulfurous stench when hot. If it were an exhaust leak it would noticed  a lot sooner and have a noise as well.